# How to run script on boot from a Debian Image?

Tags: linux, boot, debian, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to create a custom Raspberry Pi OS (Debian based) image that runs a script after the device boots up. My question: is there a way I can add a script to the Debian image that will run when the image is booted up?

Here's the order of operations I'm aiming for:

1. Build custom Debian image on local machine.
2. Mount image on local machine. Add script file.
3. Write image to microSD card.
4. Boot device with microSD card. Run script on boot.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Scheduling a task with Crontab? With that you can run your Python script every time the Raspberry Pi reboots.
open the crontab editor with:

```
    crontab -e
```

you can check out the docs here
(https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md)
scroll down to instructions on reboot

Comment: Sadly Crontab doesn't fit my needs - I want to add the script file directly to the `.img` volume before the device is booted for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. You can add a script to `.img` volume and create a custom kernel that looks for the script on boot.

Let's say you're flashing a microSD with the image `debian.img`. Everything in `debian.img` is stored under `/boot` when the target device (in this case, a Raspberry Pi) boots and runs.

The key is that you must first create a custom Debian kernel that searches `/boot` for your script when the device boots. Within the kernel, you can use `crontab` or another method to do this on boot. You must make sure this is done before you build the kernel for the image you'll be flashing.